# Keyboard strokes with windows services

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

Is it possible to emulate key presses with a windows service?  For example say I have a service running in the background that anytime a trigger occurs for example the trigger could be it's 2:00PM then I would for example press window key+L to lock computer.  Would this be possible in C#?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Regardless of what approach you take, you'll probably need to get your system service to launch a subprocess in the user's session.  Possibly useful API calls include  WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId, WTSQueryUserToken, and CreateProcessAsUser.  (Theoretically another option is to use a device driver, but that's even more complicated.)

Answer (score 2):

I realized that you want only to lock your computer.

By using this code, you can lock your computer same as <kbd>Windows Logo</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

```
[DllImport("user32")]
public static extern void LockWorkStation();
```

and about the time. it might be look like this.

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
if (d.TimeOfDay.Hours >= youSettedTime)
{
  LockWorkStation();
}
```

Reference: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/7aab9893-430a-4aed-8d51-b8368a61860e/

Comment: Does this work from session 0?  Surely it locks the workstation for the session it is running in, rather than the session the user is logged into?

Comment: I apologize but I did not test :), but if the OP mentioned about the `session` it might be another problem.